# Is there any disk check software for GNU/Linux that can work with NTFS partitions made by Windows 7?

Tags: 64-bit, ubuntu-10.04, ntfs, scan-disk

I'm having problems with scandisk on windows 7. After I schedule it, I get the countdown and it either hangs on 1 second or does nothing. I believe that I should run it on my primary windows partition, so I'm asking for some alternatives.

It's a plus if it's available for 64bit Ubuntu 10.04, but live cds or programs which may need to be compiled form command line are also acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use ntfsfix in the ntfs-3g suite. It is a package.

Comment: I'll try it out.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ntfsprogs there you go

Comment: I used it on my partition, but as far as I can see it did nothing. Also, how much time does it take to scan 202GiB partition on 5400RPM disk? For me it was finished in about 3 seconds.

Comment: @AndrejaKo well, did it give any output? make sure you run fdisk -l to find the right device, then make sure you are superuser when running ntfsfix. you can try this in windows 7 as well: http://www.w7forums.com/use-chkdsk-check-disk-t448.html it's newer than scandisk

Comment: Scheduled CHKDISK does nothing for me (described behaior is from it). ntfsfix did not give any output which indicates anything wron. Yes, I'm sure that I'm using right device, I checked with GParted before I used it. I'll get exact output and post it when I boot Ubuntu next time.